# IP Whitelisting between two AWS Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, whitelist

I am new to AWS, so this question may be very basic. We have a couple of Microservices hosted across different AWS accounts.

For example, "Order management" API is developed in Spring boot and hosted in AWS account "Alpha" on EKS platform, whereas "Customer Management" Microservice is hosted in AWS Account "Beta" on Elastic Beanstalk. Apart from "Customer Management" Microservice, there are many other applications hosted in "Beta" AWS account.

My question is how do we set IP whitelisting rule on "Order management" API so that traffic coming from "Customer Management" Microservice can only have access to the "Order management" API? In other words, I do not want every Application/Service hosted in  "Beta" AWS account to have access to "Order management" API.

Comment: Do the two services only communicate via Public IP (since they are in different AWS Accounts)? Do you have Security Groups in place on the servers that control incoming access to each service? If so, have you tried adding an Inbound rule to the Security Groups to limit access based on IP address?

Comment: Are you using VPC peering?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve your problem quickly:

- Assigning static IPs on NAT gateways will ensure a reliable outbound IP address for all the instances running inside the private subnets of a VPC.
- You can then whitelist a combination of static IP assigned to the NAT gateway and the ports used by your applications (HTTP 80, HTTPS 443, etc.)
- If you have NACLs in place, make sure that desired traffic is capable of passing through as well.

A more secured and scalable solution would look like:

- (Quick fix and non-ideal) Have your two VPCs connected via VPC peering so that the traffic don't have to go outside of AWS.
- If you expect the number of VPCs to grow in the longer run, you can introduce a Transient gateway which enables your organization to connect their on-premise networks via VPN to different VPCs across multiple accounts.

PS: You have to consider the CIDRs and network segmentation as well so you can allocate the appropriate number of hostnames to each subnet across the accounts to reduce complexity of network setup.

Cost is another thing to consider too! If you just want a simple connectivity between the two accounts without complicated setup, maybe security groups, static IPs and NACLs will be enough. If you have enough budget to setup the transient gateways and VPNs, then that would be a more secure and scalable solution for the network too.